# algoritmo para remover elementos repetidos em python

Tags: python-3.x

Escreva um algoritmo que elimine de uma pilha P todos os elementos iguais a um certo valor X, mantendo os valores restantes na pilha na mesma ordem relativa em que se encontram.
Observação: Só são permitidas operações de desempilhamento e empilhamento.
Dica: Utiliza uma pilha auxiliar Q para resolver este problema.

consegui fazer, mas eles pedem com empilhamento e desempilhamento

Comment: Olá, coloque o código na pergunta para os usuários analisarem

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, você precisa lembrar que uma pilha possui o comportamento LIFO, do inglês *last input, first output*; i.e. o último a entrar será o primeiro a sair. Assim, ao desempilhar elementos de P e empilhar em Q, a ordem em Q ficará invertida, então você precisará inverter a ordem de Q voltando os elementos para P.

O algoritmo é basicamente este:

1. Enquanto P não estiver vazia:

   - Desempilha um elemento de P;
   - Se o elemento for igual a X, volte ao passo 1;
   - Empilha o elemento em Q;
2. Enquanto Q não estiver vazia:

   - Desempilha um elemento de Q;
   - Empilha o elemento em P;

Ou seja:

```
P: Pilha<elementos de P>
Q: Pilha<vazia>

Enquanto P não estiver vazia faça:
    Elemento = P.desempilha()
    Se Elemento é diferente de X:
        Q.empilha(Elemento)

Enquanto Q não estiver vazia faça:
    Elemento = Q.desempilha()
    P.empilha(Elemento)
```

Ao final, a pilha P será a pilha original, na mesma ordem, sem os elementos que forem iguais a X.

Se é em Python, muita coisa pode ser simplificada durante a implementação em código.

Comment: isso"  pode criar uma classe com as funções def() tabm? eu acho